# get_headers и file_get_contents HTTP request failed!

Tags: php

Имею вот такой код

```
        $url = $_GET['url'];
        $checksite = get_headers($url, 1);
        $page_content = file_get_contents($url);
        if($checksite['0'] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'){
          ...
        }
        print_r($checksite);
```

Проблема в том что если подставить как GET параметр http://vk.com/ или http://google.com/ или любой другой сайт то get_headers и file_get_contents выполняют свои обязанности но если же подставить http://cmstools.ru/ начинают сыпаться ошибки

**Warning**: get_headers(http://cmstools.ru/) [function.get-headers]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in L:\home\share.ru\www\test.php on line 21

**Warning**: file_get_contents(http://cmstools.ru/) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in L:\home\share.ru\www\test.php on line 22

В чем может быть проблема? тот сайт на IPB, может дело в его движке?

p.s работаю на Denwer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему, http://cmstools.ru/ некорректно отрабатывает запросы по протоколу HTTP 1.0, т.к. даже простое

```
curl -s 'http://cmstools.ru/' -0
```

не может отобразить сайт (при этом по HTTP 1.1 сайт отдается нормально). Остальные же ссылки грузятся нормально по любому протоколу.

В то же время, согласно документации [Опции контекста HTTP](http://php.net/manual/ru/context.http.php):

> > protocol_version - По умолчанию 1.0.
> >
> > **Замечание:**
> >
> > В PHP до версии 5.3.0 не было реализовано декодирование фрагментированных передач. Если это значение установлено в 1.1, то это ваша ответственность, чтобы оно соответствовало версии 1.1.

Т.е. если перед вызовом функций указать соответствующий контекст, то код будет отрабатывать как надо:

```
stream_context_set_default(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'protocol_version' => '1.1',
        ),
    )
);
$url = 'http://cmstools.ru/';
$checksite = get_headers($url, 1);
$page_content = file_get_contents($url);
print_r($checksite); // будут выведены заголовки
```