# почему get_headers и file_get_contents отдают false, если файлы реально существуют?

Tags: php

```
$a = [
'http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/s.00419.png',
'http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/s.00440.png',
'http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/cf.01782.png',
'http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/pr.25474600.png',
'http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/pr.25474400.png',
'http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/w.62822.png',
'http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/w.00535.png',
'http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/988657_1.png',
'http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/XD10028.png',
'http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/w.00511.png',
'http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/XD10026.png',
'http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/f.U4604101_SafetyLock.png'
];

stream_context_set_default(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'protocol_version' => '1.1',
        ),
    )
);
        
foreach ($a as $url){
    $c = get_headers($url, 1);
    $d = file_get_contents($url);

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($c);
    echo '</pre>';
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($d);
    echo '</pre>'; 
}
```

Все указанные файлы реально есть на сервере и открываются в браузере. Также они открываются и по протоколу https. Но указанные функции возвращают false. Почему?
Вот этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/445648/get-headers-%D0%B8-file-get-contents-http-request-failed) не помог.

Comment: обычно file_get_contents генерирует ошибку при невозможности открыть ссылку

Comment: так в браузере они все открываются

Comment: обычно. file_get_contents. генерирует. ошибку. В которой. написано. почему. она. не смогла. открыть. файл

Comment: https://ideone.com/72GVb5 PHP Warning:  get_headers(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in /home/erwJ80/prog.php on line 27
PHP Warning:  get_headers(http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/s.00419.png): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in /home/erwJ80/prog.php on line 27

Comment: что означает не удалось открыть поток и временный сбой в разрешении имён - хз)

Comment: при чем здесь ideone? с какой стати песочница должна тягать вам файлы?

Comment: string(117) "file_get_contents(http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/pr.25474400.png): failed to open stream: Connection timed out"

Comment: настройка [allow_url_fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) включена?

Comment: да, конечно. Обращу внимание на то, что массив ранее был намного больше - там и другие картинки есть и их я обработал. Остались те, которые не обрабатываются, т.к. "взяться не за что"

Comment: Так что, есть идеи?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно Вы слишком часто "долбили" данный сервис и попали под бан (может временный, может постоянный).
Попробуйте сменить либо свой ip, либо запустить на другом сервере данный скрипт, ибо то что вы предоставили во всяком случае у меня запустилось без проблем (php 7.4.3) и отдало и картинки и хедеры.
Проверил даже без указания stream_context_set_default - все работает замечательно. Как вариант - еще раз точно перепроверьте на "allow_url_fopen" либо через ini_get, либо через phpinfo()